# Extend Class without changing its name

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a situation: In a single Solution I have two Projects. I need to extend the Class:**Foo** used in Project:**A** so that I can add new functionality required in Project:**B** without changing its name. Problem is: Class:**Foo** already contains (i.e. has a) Class:**Bar** and is contained by Class:**Goo** in both Project:**A** & Project:**B**. In Project:**B** I am inheriting Class:**Goo** into Class:**Goo_Ex**; but I need to also extend both: Class:**Foo** and Class:**Bar** with  companion functions.

To make it more clear - I could accomplish this using the following *crude* method:

```
/* Project:A-Class:Foo */

class Foo
{
    .
    .
    .
# ifdef PROJECT_B
    fnExtended();
# endif
};
```

but that would litter my code in Project:A.

A possible solution that I can think of is to use Inheritance and have Class:**Foo_Global** Inherited-[Only] as Class:**Foo** in Project:**A** and Inherited-[Extend] as, again, Class:**Foo** in Project:**B**; same for Class:**Bar**. But is their a more straight forward solution..?

Comment: Could you please clarify why you would want to do this? I am curious to see if there is a real-life use-case for this.

Comment: A general exemplification of my specific case will be more fruitful. Thus: I have a hierarchical structure where the _parent_ class contains ('_has a_') child classes. the child further 'contains' _grand-child_. The thing is this same structure is used for different purposes in two different (inter-related) projects. again Project B requires additional functionality but this has to be achieved without breaking the original structure :: meaning without changing any class names.

Comment: Closure: I used inheritance as described in the proposed solution. In project:A I have: **# include <FooClass.h>** instead of **# include "FooClass.h"** within **GooClass.h** Such that each project includes its local copy of Class:Foo which is **Only-Inherited** in case of Project:A but **Inherited-Extended** in Project:B. Same for Class:Bar. I had to add _Additional Include Directory_ in compiler settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proposed solution (to hide the current Foo as some other class name and inherit from it in a new Foo class in both projects) is how you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really abstract problem, and it's difficult to give you a good specific solution without more details.

The basic way of handling this is inheritance. But this requires some pre-planning. It means that when you refer to Foo in project A, you should use pointers or references. If you create a Foo (and need code from project A create Foo_Extended when it's part of project B) then you need to have a configurable Foo factory that will create objects of the appropriate type depending upon context.

The other way of handling this is templates. You never have the code in project A refer directly to the global Foo class. Instead it always refers to a template parameter. In project A that template parameter will end up resolving to Foo, and in project B it will resolve to some other class that has the needed functionality.

These are the two general ways of handling this issue in C++. And which you use depends a lot on the details of the context in which you're using them.

Comment: Sir I seek a compile-time solution. What you suggest appears to be in Run-time. am I correct?

Comment: @San0013: No, it's compile time.

Comment: But both these solutions appear to be overtly complicated than my self-proposed solution which already uses inheritance.

Comment: Templates and Class-Factory are compile-time, yes. I seek a solution that is- 'source-time' (if I may call it that) i.e. the code is clearly separated across Project:A and Project:B and absolutely without any overlapping.

Comment: @San0013: _shrug_ Oh, well. Those features were specifically design to make it easier to have re-usable code so you could re-use the features of project A in project B without having to modify it. But if you don't want to use them, then I have no help for you. Your requirements seem very contorted and specifically design to make sure there isn't a way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The way to extend you class is not to extend it! Just use a function taking suitable arguments instead.

Comment: That's the most basic solution. but the ideology here is to not contaminate Project:A's code with code required only in Project:B. Bottom line: that extended code should not appear in Project:A's source code.

Comment: So you declare and define this function in files not included in projects which don't use it. The corresponding code may even go into its own library project. I guess I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: problem is this function is due to become part of the same class used in Project:A. Can you think of a solution to break the above code for Class:Foo in to two separate files without overlapping code.

Comment: All done: you just include the header in Project A when you need it! Just stop believing that functions need to be the member of any class and you are all sorted out.

Comment: I wish to have the header file clean as well.. the above code of Class::Foo is in the header file.

Comment: Somewhere in the transmission information gets lost: I'll try in very simple terms... 1. create an empty header files, 2. include the header for the class you want to extend and put the functionality you want to extend your type by into this header, 3. create an empty source file, 4. include the just created header and implement the new functionality. Optionally, before doing any of this, create a new project where these files go. This can now be included where needed and, obviously, omitted where it is no needed.

Comment: Sir: please refer to my comment to the question. This is not a simple case. I have to extend the Class **without** changing its name. Still from our discussion i have a new direction of thought to have two different header files defining the same class-name one with base structure and another with extended structure. Still though that's an overlap (redundancy) of some code in header files.

Comment: I think what I don't get through is this: Do **not** use a **member** function. Instead, **do use a non-member** function! I know, this is blasphemous to the gods of object orientation but just realize that this religion has some merits but requiring everything to be a member function is a folly. If you need the function to be a member of something because this what was decreed by the misguided prophets make it a static member of a separate class.